.htaccess Rewrite Causes CGI 404
I'm trying to set up a site on a hosting service to share test pages with a client. The client uses a non-standard path for their pages and I have to include that path in the pages for a CGI script they use. I have an .htaccess file at the root that looks like this, where docs is the directory that contains the pages:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xxx/yyyy/zzzz/docs/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxx/yyyy/zzzz/docs/$1 [L,PT,QSA]
<Directory "/cgi-bin/">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-cript .cgi .pl
    Require all granted
</Directory>

This serves the pages, but I get a 404 when I try to run a CGI script. If I comment out the Rewrite lines, the script runs, but I get a 404 on the pages. I've also tried placing the CGI folder in the docs folder and revising the CGI directory path to /xxx/yyyy/zzzz/docs/cgi-bin/, but I still get the same 404 problem.
